# Verificar se existe o símbolo de porcentagem (%) junto do número

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como verificar se existe ou não o simbolo de % junto com o valor?

O código abaixo é uma versão simplificada. O resultado final é que a variável `taxas` terá ou não a porcentagem junto do numero.

Se tiver % irei fazer o calculo segundo ele. Se não tiver % farei o calculo simples.

> Erro: taxas.includes is not a function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var formaID = "1";
  var formaTaxa = "3.55";
  var formaTipo = "%";


  if (formaID == "") {
    var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val("0.00");
  } else {
    var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val(formaTaxa + formaTipo);
  }




  if (taxas.includes("%") == true) {
    console.log("Tem %");
  } else {
    console.log("Não tem %");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Duplicada e do mesmo autor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398486/usar-o-simblo-de-no-input-maskmoney?noredirect=1#comment782686_398486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que você está usando o `.includes()` no objeto do elemento e não no seu valor, por isso o erro.

Ao fazer:

```
var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val("0.00");
```

Você está alterando o valor do elemento `#formaTaxas` e atribuindo à variável `taxas` o próprio elemento.

O método `.includes()` só funciona com [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) ou com [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Você teria que usar `.val()` antes do `.includes()` para pegar o valor do campo e verificar se contém o caractere:

```
taxas.val().includes("%")
```

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var formaID = "1";
  var formaTaxa = "3.55";
  var formaTipo = "%";


  if (formaID == "") {
    var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val("0.00");
  } else {
    var taxas = $("#formaTaxas").val(formaTaxa + formaTipo);
  }




  if (taxas.val().includes("%") == true) {
    console.log("Tem %");
  } else {
    console.log("Não tem %");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="formaTaxas">
```

Só se atente ao fato de que o `.includes()` tem menos compatibilidade que o `.indexOf()`, que pode, nesse caso, fazer a mesma coisa.

Veja tabelas no Can I Use: [.includes()](https://caniuse.com/#search=.includes) / [.indexOf()](https://caniuse.com/#search=.indexof)

Answer (score 3):

Troque o `taxas.includes` para `taxas.indexOf`.

A função `indexOf` retorna o índice do caractere na string e caso não exista, retorna **-1**.

```
if (taxas.indexOf("%") > -1) {
    console.log("Tem %");
} else {
    console.log("Não tem %");
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
function hasPercent(value) {
  return value.indexOf('%') > -1 ? true : false;
}

console.log('30 -> ' + hasPercent('30'));
console.log('30% -> ' + hasPercent('30%: '));
```

Comment: Vitor, é errado fazer dessa forma `var formaTaxas    = $("#formaTaxas").val(formaTaxa+formaTipo);` ou seja, estou armazenando o valor dentro da variável e ao mesmo tempo jogando o valor `formaTaxa+formaTipo` para o `imput` `#formaTaxas`.?

Comment: Não é errado dependendo do fim que deseja. O por que está definindo o valor para o `input`? No exemplo que passou nunca terá o símbolo `%` porque você define o valor para `0.00`.